# Votes tab redirecting to downvotes tab on actual vote page

Tags: bug, votes

When I click on the `votes` tab, it goes [my votes page](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/20912/zixuan?tab=votes) on HTTPS but also goes to the downvotes tab in the actual `votes` page.

Is this a bug or not?

Answer (score 1):

It's by-design, SE remembers your last selection of the tab.

I'm not certain if "downvotes" tab is the default one (I believe it should be "all"), but if your last selection is on the "downvotes" tab when leaving the page, then SE will redirect to there again when accessing the "votes" tab.

Comment: When I did not have the down vote privilege, it redirects to the up vote tab.